# Whats the fastest way to extract "external links" data from dbpedia (or wikipedia)?

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia, wikipedia-api

I need to get the "external links" links from specific Wikipedia articles in an array in either jquery (preferable) or php. I've gone through the wikipedia api and it doesn't seem there's a way to do that. It looks like there is a way to do it in dbpedia (the dbpedia.org/resource/etc pages show a "dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink" section), but I've never used sparkql and have no idea how to use it in conjunction with jquery or php.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following query in the sparql query form at http://dbpedia.org/sparql

```
select ?link where 
{
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rome> 
 <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink> 
 ?link
} LIMIT 100
```

Then look at the browser address bar of the results page to understand how to encode the query via GET.

Otherwise you can have a look at http://json.it.dbpedia.org

have fun!

Comment: Ok, that's definitely helped me further! The problem now is that when I choose "json" from your first link, it doesn't open it in the browser (it just download the file), so I can't really see how the json GET works. The second link, on the other hand, doesn't seem to offer the option to only get the "wikiPageExternalLink" links. If I have to, I guess I can work with the entire file and extract those links, though it would be a shame! If you can help me further here, that would be really great!

Comment: On Jsonpedia you can: enter `__type:link` in the _filter_ field and then select the _extractors_ and _Structure_ buttons. 

On dbpedia you can select the _html_ output, look at the URL and the adjust the parameters in the GET query string to get json.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for prop=extlinks.

Here's an example that gets all the links in the article "Germany" in the English Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extlinks&format=json&ellimit=5000&titles=Germany

You can tweak it using the API sandbox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox .

Comment: thanks, but I wish it was so simple :-(. I knew about "prop=extlinks", but that gives you every single link on the page. I specifically need the ones that are at the end of the article in the "External Links" section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dump [0] with the text version solely, and then parse the text. For example, you can search for external links in the text after "== External links ==", or other templates for external links [1].

0 - http://dumps.wikimedia.org/

1 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:External_links

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract all external links from wikipedia (from all pages), there is a tool for that: [wikipedia-externallinks-fast-extraction](https://github.com/lovasoa/wikipedia-externallinks-fast-extraction)